# Trim String to int, then char to string, Listbox to textbox

Tags: c#, listbox

Im getting Formart Exception was unhandled. Help...

Im trying to convert the first character of a string in a listbox to a int.

```
listBox2.Items.Add(" 1            " + seatArray[0].PrintInfo);

// I take the first char in the string
string test = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim();

//convert to int, here Im getting Formart Exception was unhandled
int num = Convert.ToInt32(test); 

//so i can use that int and summon the value A in the seat class.
textBox2.Text = seatArray[num].A.ToString();
```

here is the class

```
public class Seats 
{
    public char A;
    public char B;
    public char C;
    public char D;
    public char E;
    public char F;

    public Seats()
    {
        A = '.';
        B = '.';
        C = '.';
        D = '.';
        E = '.';
        F = '.';
    }
```

This is all so I can take each value(ABC DEF) of the object of the class in the listbox, to the right textbox.

Comment: Okay, you forgot to ask a question though. There isn't really even an implied question. Can you please elaborate on what the problem is currently?

Comment: convert to int, here Im getting Formart Exception was unhandled

Comment: Of course you are, its looking for a numerical character and you are passing in a letter... are you expecting the ascii value or its "position" in the alphabet?

Comment: string.Trim() does not take the first character. It removes leading and trailing whitespace characters. test[0] takes the first character

Comment: how I take the first character, so i can take number 1?

Comment: Use `String.Substring()`.

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I convert from string to int in c# from a Listbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785610/how-do-i-convert-from-string-to-int-in-c-sharp-from-a-listbox?rq=1), Update your existing question..

Comment: String.Substring() will return a string. If you want a char, you can simply use the indexer: test[0] (after you've done Trim() )

Answer (score 0):

A format exception, according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx) means:

> *value* does not consist of an optional sign followed by a sequence of digits (0 through 9).

Whatever you're getting on this line:

```
string test = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim();
```

Is not an parse-able integer. You should debug to figure out what the value is that you're actually getting.

**Hint**: `Trim` does not grab the first character of the string. A quick google for some code examples on how to grab a substring or the first character of a string should find you what you need.

Once you've figured out getting the first character correctly, you can either wrap your code in a try-catch (example from the documentation):

```
try {
  result = Convert.ToInt32(value);
  Console.WriteLine("Converted the {0} value '{1}' to the {2} value {3}.",
                    value.GetType().Name, value, result.GetType().Name, result);
}
catch (OverflowException) {
   Console.WriteLine("{0} is outside the range of the Int32 type.", value);
}   
catch (FormatException) {
  Console.WriteLine("The {0} value '{1}' is not in a recognizable format.",
                     value.GetType().Name, value);
}
```

Or you can use [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) and look at the boolean result to see if the parse completed successfully.